# Collecting data in a for loop (using a different structure than what I'm used to)

Tags: r, indexing

I know this question gets asked a lot. I'm comfortable with collecting data in a for loop by creating an object outside of the loop to iteratively store observations.

However, I'm making a k-fold cross validation function, and came across this nice function from stats.stackexchange: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105839

```
  #Randomly shuffle the data
yourData<-yourData[sample(nrow(yourData)),]

#Create 10 equally size folds
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(yourData)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

#Perform 10 fold cross validation
for(i in 1:10){
    #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- yourData[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- yourData[-testIndexes, ]
    #Use the test and train data partitions however you desire...
}
```

I guess I'm used to seeing the indexing variable 'i' used throughout the code. When I try to store each iteration of some downstream variable (let's say the miss-classification rate of some linear classifier, stored in a vector `miss_class`). It doesn't work like I'm used to; I can only store the first iterated value when I try `miss_class[i]<-#relevant code within loop[i]`.

I know this is vague, and without reproducible code, but I'd appreciate some insight. Thanks.

Comment: While this will work, it's better not to work in a loop. If you don't want to use `boot::cv.glm`, `modelr::crossv_kfold` or similar, try making a data.frame with a list column of indices, which you can then use `lapply` or `Map` to iterate across to add new columns, which can later be aggregated if you like. This method gives you lots of control and organization without long loop environments to track.

Answer (score 0):

While a loop will work, if you want to avoid `boot::cv.glm`, `modelr::crossv_kfold` and the like, a good organizational strategy is to stick everything in a data.frame, starting with a list column of indices for each fold. Once you've done that, you can easily `lapply` or `Map` across that column to add new columns based on that subset of data—even including full models, if you like. A simple example:

```r
set.seed(47)

df <- data.frame(k = seq(10))

# add list column of indices
df$indices <- split(seq(nrow(iris)), 
                    sample(cut(seq(nrow(iris)), 10, labels = FALSE)))

# add models as list column
df$model <- lapply(df$indices, function(i){lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris, subset = i)})
# extract adjusted R^2 to new column
df$adj_r_squared <- sapply(df$model, function(m){summary(m)$adj.r.squared})

dplyr::tbl_df(df)    # base R print method gets out of hand
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>        k    indices    model adj_r_squared
#>    <int>     <list>   <list>         <dbl>
#>  1     1 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8824608
#>  2     2 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.6168011
#>  3     3 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8843492
#>  4     4 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8827520
#>  5     5 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8651278
#>  6     6 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.9331991
#>  7     7 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.9351074
#>  8     8 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8997065
#>  9     9 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8915772
#> 10    10 <int [15]> <S3: lm>     0.8434274

# aggregate
data.frame(mean_r_squared = mean(df$adj_r_squared), 
           sd_r_squared = sd(df$adj_r_squared))
#>   mean_r_squared sd_r_squared
#> 1      0.8634509    0.0909918
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned about the append function while searching for an answer. After creating an empty vector via: vec<-c(), you can use: vec<-append(vec,info) to store data from a for loop in this format.